# A bound for modulus of convolution like Young's inequality.

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to know whether following pointwise estimate holds:

$$
|(f\ast g)(x)|\le |f(x)| C(g)
$$

where $C(g)$ may be $ \| g \|_{L^1}$ and domain of all functions is $\mathbb{R^n}$.

If I use Young's convolution inequality, (essential) supremum yields uniformness in $x$. Also, since $\sup_x f \le \sup_x g$ does not imply $f(x) \le g(x)$ generally, it may fail. How can I prove or disprove above estimates ?

Comment: This is false. ROughly speaking, take $f$ to be compactly supported, and $g$ not compactly supported. Then, $f*g$ won't necessarily have compact support, while the RHS of your inequality does. This would give a contradiction. I'll leave it to you to figure out the specifics.

Comment: If an assumption that $f$ and $g$ are compactly supported is added, is it true? Or, what if they have same compactly supported set?

Comment: Still no. Convolution typically increases the size of the support to roughly the "sum" of the supports (just look at the formula for convolutions). Imagine a bell-shape function strictly positive on $(-1,1)$, vanishing at the endpoints, and try to think of what $f*f$ looks like. It's support will increase beyond $(-1,1)$, (in particular $f*f$ will be strictly positive at the point $x=1.5$ for instance) so the pointwise bound you seek cannot hold. Pointwise bounds for convolutions aren't a good idea.